# JavaScript Extract HTML Tag from a String

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I have the following string:

```
let html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
    </body>
</html>`;
```

How can I extract just the opening HTML tag? I only need:

```
'<html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">'
```

Please suggest a regular expression if that is the best way.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to capture the `<html>` tag, you can simply use `/<html.*>/`.

This simply searches for `<html` followed by any numbers of characters, then ends on the next `>`.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
let html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
    </body>
</html>`;

console.log(html.match(/<html.*>/)[0]);
```

And seen on **[Regex101 here](https://regex101.com/r/We2iiJ/1/)**.

Comment: I changed the regex to /<html.*?\>/ to disable greedy matching. That way, it works if the string is, e.g. : "<html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>." (No newline after the first >)

Comment: You'd also want to use `<html[^>]*>` which is much more faster. @GTSJoe

Comment: @revo What is the difference besides the speed?

Comment: Better performance comes from the reason that `[^>]*` denotes a greedy match but `.*?` is non-greedy. The former consumes all characters except `>` at once then matches `>` but latter consumes one character at a time until it reaches a `>`. There is no difference other than speed except `[^>]*` is able to go across multiple lines too. @GTSJoe

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to extract the second line, you can split your string by \n and get the value of the desired line

```js
let html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
    </body>
</html>`;

var lines = html.split(/\n/g);
console.log(lines[1]);
```